# my conditional text is not reflecting on the page when the function is called

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, innertext

It seems the result variable is not defined, what did i do wrong?

In html I called the function using the the `onclick` attribute, giving both my buttons parameters.

In `pickCompterMove()` I used `math.random` to specify heads or tails.

My console does not detect any errors.

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text');


function playGame(playerMove) {

  computerMove = pickComputerMove();
  let result = '';

  if (playerMove === 'heads') {
    if (computerMove === 'heads') {
      result = 'You win';
    } else if (computerMove === 'tails') {
      result = 'You lose';
    }
  } else if (playerMove === 'tails') {
    if (computerMove === 'heads') {
      result = 'You lose';
    } else if (computerMove === 'tails') {
      result = 'You win';
    }
  }
  text.innerText = result;

}
```

Comment: could you please provide all your relevant data? including the HTML, how are you calling your `playGame` function, how are you sending the parameters it receives? give more details about the question and format it better plz

Comment: I edited your question, created a snippet, please edit the snippet and provide the HTML and all the relevant code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Did the two options work for your code? if it did kindly accept it with the check mark right below the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you included HTML in the code. Your code may not have worked because the function `pickComputerMove()` wasn't stated, but called in the code.

```js
function pickComputerMove() {
        // This function randomly picks either 'heads' or 'tails' for the computer's move
        return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
    }

    function playGame(playerMove) {
        const text = document.getElementById('text');
        const computerMove = pickComputerMove();
        let result = '';

        if (playerMove === 'heads') {
            if (computerMove === 'heads') {
                result = 'You win';
            } else if (computerMove === 'tails') {
                result = 'You lose';
            }
        } else if (playerMove === 'tails') {
            if (computerMove === 'heads') {
                result = 'You lose';
            } else if (computerMove === 'tails') {
                result = 'You win';
            }
        }
        text.innerText = result;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="text"></div>
    <button onclick="playGame('heads')">Play Heads</button>
    <button onclick="playGame('tails')">Play Tails</button>
```

In case you want to move out of what you already have and want a shorter line of code, you have the option below, works the same just shorter than the initial code:

```
function pickComputerMove() {
    // This function randomly picks either 'heads' or 'tails' for the computer's move
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
}

 playGame = playerMove => document.getElementById('text').textContent = pickComputerMove () == playerMove ? 'You win':'You lose';
```

Comment: The `playGame()` function can be written as a one-liner: `playGame=playerMove=>document.getElementById('text').textContent=pickComputerMove()==playerMove?'You win':'You lose';`.